# Form_AfterUpdate is lost during a SubForm.Recordset change

Tags: ms-access, vba, subforms

I've got a problem with SubForms in Access, there is something I don't understand.
I have a Form (frm) with a control (combo) and the form contains a Subform (subfrm).
In debugmode i make two breakpoints, one at combo_AfterUpdate and another at frm_AfterUpdate. if I change the data in the combo everything seems fine:

stop at combo_AfterUpdate > (save form) > stop at frm_AfterUpdate

now I add code to my combo_AfterUpdate eventhandler that changes the subfrm.Form.Recordset:

stop at combo_AfterUpdate > (save form) > ...

no stop at frm_AfterUpdate!?
anyone knows why?

EDIT:
here the code that executes in combo_AfterUpdate:

```
If Not IsNull(Me!childID) Then
    Dim childSubSource As QueryDef
    Set childSubSource = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_parent_Detail_child_WithParam")
    childSubSource.Parameters("childID").Value = Me!childID
    Set frmChildSub.Form.Recordset = _
        childSubSource.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
End If
```

EDIT:
interesting.. if I change

```
Set frmChildSub.Form.Recordset = _
    childSubSource.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

to

```
frmChildSub.Form.Recordsource= childSubSource.SQL
```

the events are working as intended. i checked the dirty property of the parentform and it seems that the problem lies here. if i assign a new object to the subform via .recordset the changes in the parent form are either saved or lost, anyway dirty is false again even though i changed the combobox.

Greetings

Comment: Could you post a code that "changes the subfrm.Form.Recordset"? It might be because your update gets cancelled, the form's event does not get fired

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you would swap a form's recordset after one of the controls' values changes. I suspect you're trying to do something fairly "non-standard" here. Is your change to the combo getting saved to the database or is that an unbound control?

Comment: Igor: here the code. childID is the value of the combobox.
HK1: it's a bound control and i want to swap the recordset because i need different data in the subform depending on the value in the combobox. i would use the "link master-/childfields" feauture but my parent recordset is also swapping :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it kind of makes sense to me...

In the first instance:

```
Set frmChildSub.Form.Recordset = _
    childSubSource.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

This is loading a brand new recordset into the form, and of course it won't have any dirty records, so the dirty proerty should return false.

In the second instance:

```
frmChildSub.Form.Recordsource= childSubSource.SQL
```

You are telling the form where to get it's data the next time that you load the form/data.
If you did the following:

```
frmChildSub.Form.Recordsource= childSubSource.SQL
frmChildSub.Form.Requery
```

Then I would expect the same behaviour as the first instance - simply because you are once again forcing MS Access to bring in a fresh recordset - which again, won't be dirty.

Comment: Set frmChildSub.Form.Recordset = _
    childSubSource.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
is changing the recordset of the childform, not the form i am actually in. are they related somehow even if they dont have linked master/child fields?